# Booting Problem in Dell Vostro 15-3568

Tags: boot, dell-vostro

Sometimes when I switch on my laptop a memory test runs on its own and after that the following screen appears

[image]

Or, sometimes the following window appears

[image]

I am having a great problem because of this and can't use the laptop. It would be great if anybody could help solving the matter.

Comment: A defective HDD/SSD is very likely. Consider replacing it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia This laptop still falls under warranty. I need to replace it.

Comment: Then please contact your Tech support.

Comment: Do you have a USB flash key plugged in... or maybe an external HDD?

Comment: After buying the laptop I was using at it was without any USB flash key or external HDD.